# how to generate a report using exit code in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python. I am interested in knowing how to generate an excel/ any report using exit code.

I have python scripts where use exit code to say that the script is failed/passed. I want to generate a report using the exit code(exit(0) and exit(1) )

if exit(0) generate excel report with test case as PASS
else then generate excel report with test case as FAIL

Please guide to proceed with this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind the exit report being in a .txt file, you can use the following:

```
report = open("report.out", "w")

#if fail
report.write("The script has failed")

#if passed
report.write("The script has passed!")

report.close()
```

If you want to write to an excel file, you should look into using pandas but I think a .txt file is best for this sort of thing.

If you want multiple scripts to write to the same output file, I would do as follows in each script:

```
with open("report.out", "a") as report:
    #if pass
    report.write("The script has passed")
    #if fail
    report.write("The script has failed")
```

There are 2 details here:
1. The "a" argument in the open statement simply appends to an existing file without overwriting it.
2. It may be useful to use this slightly different method of opening a file because it is best to minimize the time python spends with a file open. This reduces the risk of two scripts writing to the same file at once.

Comment: but the report is not generated. do i have to import something to generate a text file

Comment: @avi no, you should not have to import anything. The "report.out" file should automatically be made with the open statement. Do you still need help?

Comment: thanks. It's working. But I want all of my scripts status in one file. which would be easy to take a look at the status of the scripts. Please suggest on this .

Comment: @avi I updated the answer. Hopefully this is what you are looking for.